# “Be all about everything.” Is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Would that phrase be appropriate to express that I want to immerse myself in being in the moment, in everything that I have been focusing on.

Comment: It is grammatical, as a quick look in say the [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+all+about) would show. Using 'everything' as the prepositional/particulate complement is unusual and sounds odd; it would probably be interpreted (without forcing prior context) as 'globally' rather than as 'everything _that I have been focusing on_'.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the phrase is fine, though it would need more context to make its point clear, and "I'm into" might convey your point better. I think what you're looking for is either a paradox or an intentional redundancy for emphasis.

"All about" implies heightened interest in something; you're "about" one thing more than other things (Meghan Trainor is all about "that bass," to the complete exclusion of treble). You mention that your subject is "everything I have been focusing on"; this narrows your range from a universal, global "everything" to mean everything within a defined set, so your meaning would be clear if you also provided this set (Eiffel 65 is perhaps all about everything *blue*). Of course, to say that you have special focus on the area of your special focus is a tautology. Perhaps that's intentional, for emphasis; you're all about everything that you're all about.

On the other hand, you mention that you want to "immerse yourself in being in the moment." This suggests a universal one-ness that truly encompasses "everything," at least everything within the compass of "the moment." This seems like a contradiction—you have a special, heightened interest in... all things equally? But perhaps the contradiction is intentional, a paradox. Yes, your are "all about *everything*" and its universality.

However, there's a similar idiomatic construction that's more often used: "I'm into everything." This is still often used within a contextual subset, but indicates a broadening of that subset: "Do you like rock music or country?" "Aw man, I'm into everything." Perhaps this is used more often because it indicates *some degree* of interest, rather than exclusive focus (*all about* that X, 'bout that X, *no* Y). "I'm into" could also serve you well if your intent is to emphasize the limits of your focus using redundancy for emphasis: "I'm into what I'm into."